# What would be the best version of the bible for me?

Tags: bible-translation

I came across this forum while doing a little bit of research. I just want to say first I do not consider myself Christian. I was raised Christian but always felt it forced on me. I have not been to a church service for 10 years and have no interest in going right now.

That being said, I want to get a bible and read it so I can make an informed decision on what I should believe.

I am looking At purchasing a bible but don’t know what version would be best for me. I want a version that is easy to read but at the same time not an interpretation and as close to a original translation as possible.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Side note: I went to a Lutheran church for the majority of my childhood. My mother still goes to the same church. My dad is a Christian but goes to a different denomination of church. I don’t know what kind.

Comment: All translation is interpretative. That's just the nature of translation (and reading in general!) You're really spoilt for choice in English, there are lots of good translations. NIV is always a safe choice.

Comment: RSV was the Bible I grew up reading; it and the New American Bible are both easy to read. I suggest an annotated edition.

Answer (score 6):

The major translations of the Bible are the King James Version (KJV), the New International Version (NIV), the New American Standard (NAS), the New King James Version (NKJV), the English Standard Version (ESV), and the New Living Translation (NLT).

The KJV and NAS attempt to take the underlying Hebrew and Greek words and translate them into the closest corresponding English words as possible (word for word), while the NIV and NLT attempt to take the original thought that was being presented in Greek and Hebrew and then express that thought in English (thought for thought).  There are pros and cons to each type - the article will help to explain.

You may find this article helpful - it gives insights into these different translations. https://www.gotquestions.org/most-accurate-Bible-translation.html

For more detailed information into the history of how the Bible has been translated, and what those translations are, please refer to this article: https://www.gotquestions.org/Bible-versions.html

I realise this presents you with more information than you might need, but, if you are to make an informed decision as to which Bible to buy, then this is a good way to go about it.  One thing I would recommend is that you buy a Bible which contains cross-references, maps, a concordance and so much more to make the Bible come alive and to answer questions that will undoubtedly arise as to start to read.

Comment: Thanks. Which books would you recommend for "Bible which contains cross-references, maps, a concordance and so much more to make the Bible come alive and to answer questions that will undoubtedly arise as to start to read"?

Comment: I use a New International Version Study Bible, as well as an English Standard Version Study Bible.  God bless you in your search.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lesley's excellent answer, I recommend to FIRST check out BibleGateway.com which offers customizable parallel translation of dozens of English translation such as [Psalm 91 in NLT,NIV,ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+91&version=NLT;NIV;ESV) so you can have a preview.  Make sure too choose passages that have archaic sounding language; Psalms, Proverbs, and prophetic books (like Isaiah, Jeremiah, Ezekiel) are good ones to compare.  Once you decide on a **translation**, you can focus on choosing the binding (leather, paperback, etc.), the print (small, normal, large), and the extra features (maps, concordance, dictionary, articles, notes).

The website [bible-researcher.com](http://www.bible-researcher.com/versions.html) offers many objective resources to evaluate translations, including a convenient "one stop shop" to read each translation's **Preface** where the translation committee describes in great detail the translation principle used.  You can find reviews and prefaces of common translations suggested by Lesley here:

- New King James Version (NKJV 1982): [1997 Preface](http://www.bible-researcher.com/nkjv.html#preface), [Review](http://www.bible-researcher.com/nkjv.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_King_James_Version)
- New International Version (NIV 1984, 2011): [1984 Preface](http://www.bible-researcher.com/niv-preface.html), [1984 Review](http://www.bible-researcher.com/niv.html), [2011 Preface](http://www.bible-researcher.com/niv2011-preface.html), [2011 Review](http://www.bible-researcher.com/niv.2011.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_International_Version)
- New American Standard Bible (NASB 1995): [Preface](http://www.bible-researcher.com/nasb-preface.html), [Review](http://www.bible-researcher.com/nasb.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_American_Standard_Bible)
- English Standard Version (ESV 2001): [2011 Preface](http://www.bible-researcher.com/esv2011preface.pdf), [Review](http://www.bible-researcher.com/esv.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Standard_Version)
- New Living Translation (NLT 2004): [Preface](http://www.bible-researcher.com/nlt2preface.html), [Review](http://www.bible-researcher.com/nlt2.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Living_Translation)

Finally, some popular translations such as NIV and NLT have gone through different editions, so pay attention to the **year** of translation as well, which affect inclusive language (NIV after 1984 experimented with this, backtracking some in the 2011 edition), or on the other hand more neutral translation (such as the 2004 (2nd) and later editions of the NLT).  Great index of all those years:

- [20th Century English translations](http://www.bible-researcher.com/versbib10.html)
- [21st Century English translations](http://www.bible-researcher.com/versbib13.html)

Which translation is today's best seller?  See the [April 2020 CBA Bible translation list](http://christianbookexpo.com/bestseller/translations.php?id=0420).

Comment: BibleGateway.com is an excellent resource and recommendation. As an on-line resource for comparing passage translations, it is invaluable. In addition to the translations listed, the New Revised Standard Version should also be considered, as it is preferred in many settings for scholarly study, including seminaries. The American Bible Society offers descriptions of popular translations. http://bibleresources.americanbible.org/resource/a-brief-description-of-popular-bible-translations

Comment: Thanks. Which books would you recommend for " the extra features (maps, concordance, dictionary, articles, notes)"?

Comment: @Tim You keep referring to "books", but if you mean a Bible, then the usual term is "bibles" because if you say "books" people may misunderstand you to mean a non-Bible books such as Bible background textbooks or Bible commentaries.  About recommendation, let's continue discussion in the [Upper Room chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room) as comments is not the place for this.  Can you please initiate your question there?  There are other people who can recommend Bibles to you too.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I can't enter any chatroom. It requires some javascript library hosted by Google or some websites censored by CCP. By books, I mean those having " the extra features (maps, concordance, dictionary, articles, notes)" and thus more than bible,

Comment: @Tim What you're looking for is commonly called "Study Bible" and there are many options depending on the translation and features. Because NIV has been around longer there are more Study Bible options for NIV. For NLT, I recommend [NLT Illustrated Study Bible](https://www.christianbook.com/nlt-illustrated-study-bible-hardcover/9781496402004/pd/402003). For ESV, a popular one is the [ESV Study Bible](https://www.christianbook.com/esv-personal-size-study-bible-softcover/9781433530838/pd/530838), which is also available in [*Logos* software](https://www.logos.com/product/5253/esv-study-bible).

Comment: @GratefulDisciple thanks. If there are many options, it will be hard to choose. So which study bible would you like for NIV?

Comment: @Tim For NIV I recommend DA Carson edited [NIV Biblical Theology Study Bible](https://www.christianbook.com/niv-biblical-theology-study-bible-hardcover/9780310450405/pd/450403), also available in [*Logos* format](https://www.logos.com/product/53349/niv-biblical-theology-study-bible-notes).

Answer (score 0):

For Bible Study and research digital bibles with links, and references can be very helpful. There is an nice App for Android "MySword - Free Android Bible" where you can compare many different versions of the bible. It has the KJV linked with Strong's Concordance.

For Bible reading, i personally recommend a paper bible. One of my favorites  is the New Jerusalem Bible.

- It is easy read.
- It uses Yahweh in stead of LORD

This bible is not so common in the online bible portals because the copyright is still active. But there are digital and online versions to try it.

Answer (score -2):

No other translation measures up to the King James.

The modern versions are based on very different texts that fundamentally change doctrine, and omit words. (The NIV is about 36k words shorter than the King James Bible.)

The chapters, words, letters and verse numbers have precise meanings that are lost when the text is changed.

For example one of the most loved verses is:

> John 3:16 For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten
>   Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have
>   everlasting life.

The word "begotten" qualifies Jesus as the only one born of God so allows other sons, which is a marvellous thing, since:

> John 1:11 He came unto his own, and his own received him not.
>
> 1:12 But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the
>   sons of God, even to them that believe on his name:

which instructs us that we can become sons of God.

This is butchered in e.g. the ESV which has:

> "For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that
>   whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life."

When Christ speaks to his disciples in Matthew 5-7, it is precisely stated:

> Matthew 5:1 And seeing the multitudes, he went up into a mountain: and when he was set, his disciples came unto him:
>   5:2 And he opened his mouth, and taught them, saying,

The NIV paraphrase for verse 2 is:

"and he began to teach them."

This omits the word "mouth" so losing the connection with the quote from Deuteronomy in the previous chapter (Matthew 4:4).

You will hear arguments against the King James Bible mostly using outside sources, but its own words remain a consistent witness to the truth.

Comment: The KJV is a great translation for anyone who is 500 years old. If you're not that old then it's a dangerous translation because of language change. So many words have changed their meaning but the verses still make sense with the new meanings so that we're not even aware we're not getting the meaning the translators intended.

Comment: @curiousdannii are you able to give an example?

Comment: Sure, I wrote more about the KJV here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/29943/6071

Comment: None of your examples hold water for me. But indeed it is a problem that words change their meaning. A problem remedied by prayer, and meditation (Psalm 1). But if you change the words as well as their meanings then you have lost precision and meaning.

Comment: So you already knew that "conversation" had changed its meaning? Or, can you tell me what "appearance" meant in the time of the KJV? Are you going to check an early modern English dictionary constantly so that you can be sure the meanings haven't changed? That's the only way you can safely read the KJV.

Comment: When I first looked at the passages containing the word it seemed the modern sense of the word didn't fit. The bible defines many words through parallelism. "Appearance" is first mentioned in Numbers 9. "...and at even there was upon the tabernacle as it were the appearance of fire...". In Samuel "...for the LORD seeth not as man seeth; for man looketh on the outward appearance, but the LORD looketh on the heart...". The good linguists I know, learn from usage not from dictionaries. A dictionary may suggest a meaning, but it has to be discounted if it does not agree with how it is used.

Comment: Actually those verses are ones in which I'd think it does have the modern sense. But there are other verses where it doesn't, specifically 1 Thessalonians 5:22. How will you use context to tell you what meaning it has? I maintain the only safe way is to constantly use a dictionary of English from the time of the KJV, checking every single content word as you come across them.

Comment: My authority is the bible, not the authors of dictionaries, scholars, scribes, Pharisees, lexicons, grammar books, bibles sold for profit, people asserting random things on the internet. A single word change corrupts the whole meaning which goes back to what I said in my answer. Do you check every word of your dictionary before using it?

Comment: How can you trust anything from the KJV then, how do you think they learnt Greek and Hebrew other than scholars, scribes, dictionaries etc?

Comment: Through the reliability and consistency of its witness. There are many false Christs and one true Word of God.